# Sending empty value in query string parameter

Tags: jmeter

I would like to send an empty value like below.

https://www.google.com/search?q=

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

But Jmeter sends EOF instead of empty value. What is the workaround, someone please throw some light.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you're parameterizing your test using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and setting `Recycle on EOF` to `False`

[image]

then when JMeter reaches the last line of the CSV file it sends the [`csvdataset.eofstring` property value](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#csv_dataset) which is `<EOF>` by default.

The options are in:

1. Add as many empty lines as you want to send to the end of your CSV file
2. Add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

   ```
   csvdataset.eofstring=
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

Comment: Hi Dmitri.. Not the last value. Some of the API calls search start with a empty string, then other keywords coming subsequently. If i enter null, the results are wrong. If i enter space, it encoded to %20. So i want to search nothing or zero length string.

Comment: I have modified the property value but Jmeter still sending EOF